# Is seek to 0 in an opened file faster than close the file then open it again?

Tags: c, file

Suppose that I have a file opened already. I'd like to write some new content to it (overwriting any old content in the file). I want this operation to operate efficiently regardless of the size of the file.

Is seek to 0 in the already opened file faster than close the file then open it again?

Comment: I suppose it's worth trying, but I cannot imagine that closing and opening could possibly be faster than just changing a file pointer with a seek.

Comment: Changing a number to zero in the internal structure associated with the file descriptor (open file description, strictly) is a lot quicker than closing a file, let alone closing and reopening the file.

Comment: It seems to me that this would be something you could test for yourself, using an existing file. Couldn't you just write a quick benchmark on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we talk about which is faster, first we must show they are equivalent. They're not.

Just seeking to 0 is insufficient to be sure all the content is overwritten. What if the new content is shorter? You must seek and truncate to be sure.

There's no standard way to truncate an open file. POSIX has `ftruncate` and Windows has `SetEndOfFile`. `fopen(filename, "w")` is standard C. So seek and truncate brings compatibility problems.

See [Is there a guaranteed and safe way to truncate a file from ANSI C FILE pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755516/is-there-a-guaranteed-and-safe-way-to-truncate-a-file-from-ansi-c-file-pointer) and [How to truncate a file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873454/how-to-truncate-a-file-in-c).

---

There is another subtle difference around file deletion. On Unix, if you delete a file any open file handles remain open. The data remains until all file handles are closed. This is commonly exploited to have secure temp files: open the temp file for both reading and writing, immediately delete the file, and continue to read and write to the open file handle. Invisible temp file.

Let's say your file is deleted while your filehandle is open. If you seek and truncate you're still working with the same data, but there's no file. If you `fopen` you're writing to a new file. This can have behavior and security implications.

There are similar issues with file renaming. If your file got renamed while the filehandle is open, seek and truncate will work with the renamed file ([there are various non-portable ways to get the filename from a file handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188757/retrieve-filename-from-file-descriptor-in-c)).  `fopen` will open a file with the old name.

---

Which is faster? Probably seek and truncate. `fopen` will have to do that anyway, plus the overhead of locating the data associated with the filename, checking permissions, etc...

You can benchmark this easily enough. You can also use [`strace`](https://strace.io/), or the equivalent for your operating system, to look at the underlying system calls.