# How to get composite key presses using C language

Tags: c

We can use ASCII to judge which normal key is pressed in C, but how can I get a composite key, I know we can catch signal to get "Ctrl+C" and so on. but how about
other composite keys, for example: "Ctrl+K."

Comment: Mac and I use iTerm2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASCII has control codes as well.

http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm

For example `Ctrl+K` can be detected by checking the return code of `getchar()` for value `11`.

Answer (score 1):

To read all control characters, even those that are normally interpreted by your terminal (and so would not be available as program input) you would have to switch to raw "uncooked" IO. This question deals with raw IO: [Unbuffered I/O in ANSI C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647927/unbuffered-i-o-in-ansi-c/1647991#1647991)