# Understanding Input and Output in C

Tags: c, input, io, output

Consider the following code:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)  // c is of char type 
      putchar(c);
```

`getchar` retrieves one `char` from *the* keyboard. But when I observed its execution, noticed that output of `putchar` does not take place until `getchar` encounters `ENTER key`. So isn't `getchar` actually retrieving the entire string until the `ENTER` key.

**Actual Output:**

```
Hello 
Hello
```

**Wanted Output:**

```
H
H
E
E
L
L
O
O
```

Comment: I think you'll like this post (and its related posts): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104460/c-confusion-about-raw-vs-cooked-terminal-modes     Your "H H E E L L O O" example is a Reasonable theory about how it Could work.  Buffering, as described in the answers, prevents that interleaving.  Turns out there are some options you can set that should give give you the "H H E E L L O O".  The concept words "raw" vs "buffered" are not obvious until you know about them.  Happy research. :-)

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647927/unbuffered-i-o-in-ansi-c

Answer (score 2):

The stream is buffered, and the `'\n'` character flushes the buffer, so YES you need to press enter for the characters to strart "*flushing*".

Also, `// c is of type char` is wrong, since `EOF` cannot be represented then. The `getchar()` function returns `int` so `c` has to be of type `int` or `c` might overflow.

Comment: Okay. But even if the stream is buffered,  getchar needs to read one char from the buffer resulting in a true case of while loop and the same char being outputted and then the pointer in the buffer moves to the next char hence resulting in the wanted output!

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the string `Hello`, then it goes to keyboard buffer. On pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Reurn</kbd> button, this stream of characters goes to standard input buffer and from there `getchar` reads it one by one.

Note that `getchar` returns `int`, so `c` should be of `int` type.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` does not read keystrokes directly from the keyboard; it reads characters from an *input stream*, which is buffered such that input isn't sent to your program until you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you need to read individual keystrokes as they are typed, then you will be better off using a platform-specific utility such as the `getch` function in the `ncurses` library to do so.